# How does TestNG runs it's own main class by only giving the "@Test" annotation

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng

I know that *TestNG* has its own main method in TestNG class. But how does it run by only giving the "`@Test`" annotation and pom.yml dependencies?

I wanna write my own custom annotation to run annotated methods as TestNG does.

Comment: It searches for those tests by heavily using _reflection_. Apart from that, this question is too broad.

Comment: If you can get your hands on Effective Java, 3rd edition - it has a whole chapter explaining how annotations work and how to run them, by creating a naive Test framework.